# Use the disc method to find the volume of solid of revolution.

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the disc method to find the volume of solid of revolution obtained by revolving the the given region around the x-axis.

$R\quad is\quad bounded\quad by\quad the\quad graphs\quad of\quad k(x)\quad =\quad { x }^{ 2 }+x+2\quad and\quad m(x)\quad =\quad 2x+4$

My try :

$ V\quad =\quad \int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)^{ 2 } } -g(x)^{ 2 }\quad dx\\ \\ k(x)^{ 2 }\quad =\quad { x }^{ 4 }+2{ x }^{ 3 }+4{ x }^{ 2 }+2x+4\\ m(x)^{ 2 }\quad =\quad 4{ x }^{ 2 }+24x+16\\ \\ \pi \int _{ -1 }^{ 2 } \left| { x }^{ 4 }+2{ x }^{ 3 }-22x-12 \right| \quad dx\\ \\ \left| { \pi \left[ \frac { 1 }{ 4 } { x }^{ 4 }+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { x }^{ 4 }+11{ x }^{ 2 }-12x \right]  }_{ x=-1 }^{ x=2 } \right| \\ \\ \left| \pi \left[ 4+8-44-24 \right]  \right| -\left| \pi \left[ \frac { 1 }{ 4 } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } -11+12 \right]  \right| \\ \\ \frac { 217\pi  }{ 4 }  $

The answer in the book is $\frac{369\pi}{10}$

So what did i do wrong ?

--Correction

$ So\quad i\quad corrected\quad the\quad { k }^{ 2 }\quad and\quad m^{ 2 }\quad \\ \\ k^{ 2 }={ x }^{ 4 }+2{ x }^{ 3 }+5{ x }^{ 2 }+4x+4\\ { m }^{ 2 }=\quad { 4x }^{ 2 }+16x+16\\ \\ \\ \\ \pi \int _{ -1 }^{ 2 }{ \left| { x }^{ 4 }+2{ x }^{ 3 }+{ x }^{ 2 }-12x-12 \right| \quad dx } \\ \\ \left| { \pi \left[ \frac { 1 }{ 5 } { x }^{ 5 }+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { x }^{ 4 }+\frac { 1 }{ 3 } { x }^{ 3 }-6{ x }^{ 2 }-12x \right]  }_{ x=-1 }^{ x=2 } \right| \\ \\ \left| \pi \left[ \frac { 32 }{ 5 } +8+\frac { 8 }{ 3 } -24-24 \right]  \right| -\left| \pi \left[ \frac { -1 }{ 5 } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 3 } -6+12 \right]  \right| \\ \\ \frac { 464\pi  }{ 15 } -\frac { 179\pi  }{ 30 } \\ \frac { 749\pi  }{ 30 } $

still wrong answer.

Comment: Relative to the $ \ x-$ axis, $ \ m(x) \ $ is the "outer function"; that is, the area being revolved is bounded "above" by the line and "below" by the parabola. (Your limits of integration appear to be correct.)

Comment: Both $k^2$ and $m^2$ are incorrect.

Comment: I corrected them but still got a wrong answer. Can you see the edit please ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do these *without* the absolute value brackets, as I really think that is confusing the issue (and isn't even really correct...).  The line is the "upper function", so the evaluation should be

$$ \pi \ \left[ \ ( - \frac{32}{5} - 8 - \frac{8}{3} + 24 + 24 ) \ - \ (\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + 6 - 12 ) \right] $$

$$ = \ \pi \ (  - \frac{33}{5} + \frac{1}{2} - 8 - 3 + 18 + 36 ) \ = \ \pi \ (43 \ - \ \frac{61}{10} ) \ . $$

You need to be really careful with this evaluation, because the second term is evaluated at *negative* 1 , so you have to make sure you subtract the odd powers of $ \ x \ $ in the right way.  (I had to re-do this three times myself because there are so many opportunities for sign errors...)

*Sign Errors: the #1 cause of math grief, from beginners to professionals!*